# Why is it reading from the file randomly?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*this puts the numbers fomr the file into two matrices*/
void readMatrices(FILE*numbers, int array[4][4], int array2[4][4]) 
{
    int i,j,num;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            fscanf(numbers,"%d",&array[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            fscanf(numbers,"%d",&array2[i][j]);
        }
    }
}


void printMatrices(int array[4][4],int array2[4][4]) /* prints out the matrices*/
{
    int i,j,num;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",array2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 
    printf("\n");
}

    /*multiplies the matrices*/
void multiplyMatrices(int array[4][4],int array2[4][4],int result[4][4]) 
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            result[i][j] = (array[i][0]*array2[0][j])+(array[i][1]*array2[1][j])+(array[i][2]*array2[2][j])+(array[i][3]*array2[3][j]);
            printf("%d ",result[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int array[4][4],array2[4][4],results[4][4];
    FILE*numbers; 
    numbers = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    readMatrices(numbers,array,array2);
    while(array[0][0]!=0)
    {
        printMatrices(array,array2);
        multiplyMatrices(array,array2,results);
        readMatrices(numbers,array,array2);
    }
    fclose(numbers);
    return 0;
}
```

[Here is the file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gcga78imj6139nz/numbers.txt?dl=0). This reads the file but in random groups of fours rather than in order like it should be, this is an issue because it's wrong and it also won't read the `0` in the file which causes it to loop infinitely.

Comment: Because you opened it with `r` instead of `w+`.

Comment: what exactly does opening it with w+ do?

Comment: i tried opening it with w+ and i just got a ton of random numbers ;-; , it still loops infintely

Comment: So `w+` creates a new file (or deletes and overwrites the current file) for write access. `r+` opens the specified file for read/write access. `w` creates a file for write access and `r` opens a file for read only access. I meant to say `r+` not `w+` above.

Comment: ahh okay let me try that

Comment: okay so i changed it to r+, and i still get a bunch of random numbers when it complies and runs, and still loops infinitely

Comment: You should really check that the file is opened successfully before using the file stream.  You should also check that each `fscanf()` operation is successful.  It would be worth writing a function to print a 4x4 matrix which you can then invoke twice, rather than writing out almost identical code twice.  Similarly for the reading of the matrices.  Avoiding writing the same code twice is a laudable goal in most programs.

Comment: how would i check to see if the file opened successfully and check to see if the fscanf() operation was successful? ( sorry, im rather new to coding, and according to my assignment im really only supposed to have the three functions i currently have)

Answer (score -1):

well i figured it out, the equals signs in the for loop cause some errors, i don't really know why it did that but they were causing issues, thanks for the suggestions.